# How to remove objects in recycle bin Sitecore CMS with powershell scrript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, sitecore

CMS Sitecore 8.2. I have many object in recycle bin - 500k.
I want to remove object in bin with powershell. I can't find scripts ps in google.
Help me pls to solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Remove-ArchiveItem` command.

E.g. to remove item with ID `"{1BB32980-66B4-4ADA-9170-10A9D3336613}"` from Recycle Bin, use:

```
$database = Get-Database -Name "master"
$archiveName = "recyclebin"
$archive = Get-Archive -Database $database -Name $archiveName
Remove-ArchiveItem -Archive $archive -ItemId "{1BB32980-66B4-4ADA-9170-10A9D3336613}"
```

To remove all the items from Recycle Bin, use:

```
$database = Get-Database -Name "master"
$archiveName = "recyclebin"
$archive = Get-Archive -Database $database -Name $archiveName
Get-ArchiveItem -Archive $archive | Remove-ArchiveItem
```

You can find those and more examples in the documentation here: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/remove-archiveitem

Comment: Thank you Marek. Do you know, why this error?

Get-ArchiveItem : The term 'Get-ArchiveItem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify t hat the path is correct and try again.

Other steps good.....

Comment: I don't know. Official docs say it's there https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-archiveitem